# How to set parameters of a uniform distribution in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

There are `k` different uniform distributions of integer type. There ranges are not necessarily the same, say `dist1~U(0,10), dist2~U(0,5), etc.` I'm using the `uniform_int_distribution` [class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/) in C++14. Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> distRange = {4,5,2,4};
  vector< uniform_int_distribution<int> > U(distRange.size(),uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,1));

  for (int i=0; i<distRange.size(); i++)
    U[i].param( uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,distRange[i]).param() );

  return 0;
}
```

As we can see, I created a new object to change the parameters. Is there a cheaper way (number of typing, or less running time) to do that?

Comment: Why not just create the distributions with the correct parameters in the first place? E.g. loop a little and use vector `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`param_type` instances are not meant to be modified. The type doesn't have an api provided. I don't think it has exact type, i.e. it's implementation defined. So there is no legal way to set params, other instantiating it with desired ones or taking a copy of parameter set of another distribution.

But you can create your distributions in place in the vector with desired parameters:

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> distRange = {4,5,2,4};
  vector< uniform_int_distribution<int> > U;

  for(auto&& max : distRange) {
    U.emplace_back(0, max);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Emplace will invoke constuctor passing the params. So, at each loop a `uniform_int_distribution` is created directly with params you desired, by using a dedicted c'tor, instead of making up a bogus instance to reset the params later.

---

For the sake of completness: If you'd really want to go `param_type` way, you could skip making distribution copies and construct a temporary:

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> distRange = {4,5,2,4};
  vector< uniform_int_distribution<int> > U(distRange.size());

  for (int i=0; i<distRange.size(); i++)
    U[i].param(uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type(0,distRange[i]));

  return 0;
}
```

It seems redundant since `param_type` c'tor is guaranteed to mirror its distributions c'tor, so it just introduces a temporary to call a different c'tor designed to work the same way. It sounds convoluted and it is.

Comment: According to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomNumberDistribution), the param type comes with a guaranteed constructor, so at least `uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type(0, max)` would work. I'm not sure if the more concise `.param({0, max})` is guaranteed in any way to work, though. You'd need an implicit constructor and no added list constructor, although the latter seems like a pretty bad idea for an implementation to add.

Comment: Oh, I've visited the page, though i've missed the bullet and went clearly wrong on my statement. It doesn't change the optimal anser for the problem to be fair. One can even take out value of a param because `param_type` "*has a member function with the identical name, type, and semantics, as every member function of D that returns a parameter of the distribution*", no way to manipulate it though =/. Thanks for calling this. I've added the second way for the completness.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using Distr = uniform_int_distribution<int>;

    vector<Distr> u;
    for( int const b : {4,5,2,4} )
    {
        u.emplace_back( 0, b );
    }
}
```